# IQueryable.OrderBy() raises ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm querying a database view with LINQ and EF, and putting in the OrderBy() method causes the following exception to come up when ToList() is called on it:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input
```

None of my parameters are null, and the sort field is a non-nullable field (I checked the DB, and no null entries have sneaked in).

Any ideas? If it helps, I'm calling it after querying, deduping (using GroupBy().FirstOrDefault()) and ToLiost()ing that.

Comment: Show us the code you're talking about.

Comment: My best guess is that there is a null in the GroupBy logic; try doing .Select(x => x.[your groupby variable]) and make sure there are no nulls there/it works.

Comment: "None of my parameters are null" - then it is probably an error in the compiler. Or mind to give us more details?

Comment: The FirstOrDefault extension method can return null if it doesn't find any match. Thats probably your culprit.

Comment: Don't assume, be sure none of your parameters are null by using the debugger.

Comment: Definitely post your LINQ expression.

Comment: `OrderBy` has no parameter named `input`, so that is not the method throwing the given exception.

Answer (score 2):

`Queryable.OrderBy` is an extension method.

Extension methods have the signature

```
public static ReturnType SomeMethod(this SomeType someType, ...)
```

now although you are calling

```
someType.SomeMethod(...);
```

this is really just syntactic sugar for

```
SomeTypeExtensions.SomeMethod(someType, ...);
```

So if you are doing

```
someIQueryable.OrderBy(...)
```

and `someIQueryable` is `null` then you will get the `ArgumentNullException` even though it may not *look* like an argument.